# Ruby XML Parsing

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a sample XML document like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <SearchSecretsResponse xmlns="urn:thesecretserver.com">
      <SearchSecretsResult>
        <Errors/>
        <SecretSummaries>
          <SecretSummary>
            <SecretId>86</SecretId>
            <SecretName>hostName\root</SecretName>
            <SecretTypeName>Unix Root Account (SSH)</SecretTypeName>
          </SecretSummary>
        </SecretSummaries>
      </SearchSecretsResult>
    </SearchSecretsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am trying to parse it using Nokogiri. My code is

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml)
puts doc.xpath('//SecretSummary')
```

But this doesn't print anything. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to alias the namespace.

```
Nokogiri::XML(xml).xpath('//foo:SecretSummary', 'foo' =>  'urn:thesecretserver.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also remove the namespaces

```
doc.remove_namespaces!
```